# How do you get a circular reference in vs.net?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

If PROJB is referenced in PROJC, and PROJC is referenced in PROJB, and PROJA references PROJB, is that a problem?

Comment: @Blankman: Are you talking about projects in VisualStudio? If yes, please add the corresponding tags?

Comment: @Codo you are right about tags, but he mentioned vs in title

Comment: I Vote up. Because I have this scenario at a enterprise.

Comment: @Codo, I have it in the title and tags, confuseD?

Comment: @Blankman: Thanks for adding the tags. And yes, I was confused and still find your question has such a short description, it is hardly comprehensible. That's probably why you got so many downvotes. (I haven't voted.)

Comment: @Blankman : You have got 599 questions to accept answers Wow!

Answer (score 3):

> If PROJB is referenced in PROJC, and PROJC is referenced in PROJB

Just this alone is a circular reference, which is not allowed in Visual Studio and will prevent you from compiling the application.

Comment: I would left that as a comment, its not a real answer, the question was whether it may cause any problem

Comment: I'll update to clarify, circular reference implies the answer - that it is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a circular reference and is a problem. In fact you will get below error

> A reference to 'ProjC' could not be added. Adding this project as a
>   reference would cause a circular dependency.

Look at these articles...

[How to get rid of circular references in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickmalik/archive/2005/03/18/398601.aspx)

[Avoiding circular references](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/6c091061-8391-419d-97f5-cea455ea183b)

[Looking Around at Circular References](http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.com/2009/11/looking-around-at-circular-references.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your example, project C referencing B and B referencing C is a circular reference and Visual Studio will not let you do it.

Answer (score 0):

With warrent. The title says: Between projects, project A need code from project B to work and opposite. I have such a scenario at a enterprise. A work-around is a shared location for DLL files, with both projects refer their DLL to. This means no circular error within each own project.

Though, there can be situations where the compiler remove the DLL file, because of a compiler error, and then the other project stop working. This is of course ugly design but if symptoms are there already, and the enterprise are weeks or month of work away, to refactor. You Can deal with it..

You already read the effect. You can't compile project B due to missing dll for project A. And vice versa. A work-around of that problem is a manual re-copy of the removed DLL. Again: Not nice, don't do it and try to refactor if it's already there!